# Escape special characters PL/SQL without using REPLACE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, escaping

I'm trying to escape and special characters found in a string. Currently I'm using the replace function searching for any special character individually and adding \ in front of it. as shown below.

```
directory := replace(directory, ' ', '\ ');
directory := replace(directory, '(', '\(');
directory := replace(directory, ')', '\)');
directory := replace(directory, '''', ''\'');
etc
```

What I am wondering is if there is a cleaner way to execute this action?

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you escaping them?

Comment: why are you escaping `'` with `'\ ` instead of `\' `? also, there's an extra `'` in the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  regexp_replace('my ''string'' with special (characters)', '([() ''])', '\\\1')
FROM
  dual;
```

Output:

```
my\ \'string\'\ with\ special\ \(characters\)
```

Answer (score 0):

What to replace:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '\w') AS output
FROM
(
        SELECT  'perl -pe ''$_ .= "\n" unless /^$/''' AS str
        FROM    DUAL
);
```

Result:

```
 - '$ .= "\"  /^$/'
```

When it is erased:

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '\W') AS output
FROM
(
        SELECT  'perl -pe ''$_ .= "\n" unless /^$/''' AS str
        FROM    DUAL
);
```

Result:

```
perlpe_nunless
```